# Dart perform runtime subtype checking

Tags: dart, types, dart-mirrors, dart-2, dart2native

I would like to perform runtime subtype checking in Dart without using `dart:mirrors`.

What I mean by this is that given two types `A` and  `B`, either as variables with type `Type` or as type arguments on a generic class (i.e the variables being checked would be, using `List` as a dummy class, `List<A>` and `List<B>`), I would like to check if `A` is a subtype of `B`.

Here is some code written with `dart:mirrors` that performs what I want:

```dart
bool isSubtype(Type a, Type b) => reflectType(a).isSubtypeOf(reflectType(b));

// OR

bool isSubType<A, B>(List<A> a, List<B> b) => reflect(a).type.typeArguments[0].isSubtypeOf(reflect(b).type.typeArguments[0]);
```

I would like to perform this check without using `dart:mirrors`. I have tried using the following code:

```dart
bool isSubType<A, B>(List<A> a, List<B> b) => <A>[] is List<B>;
```

However, while this code works with expressions with a static type:

```dart
print(isSubType(<Iterable>[], <Iterable>[])); // true
print(isSubType(<Iterable>[], <List>[]));     // true
print(isSubType(<Iterable>[], <String>[]));   // false
```

it does not work with expressions without a static type:

```dart
List a = <Iterable>[];

List<List> types = [<Iterable>[], <List>[], <String>[]];

for (final type in types) {
  print(isSubType(type, a)); // true, true, true
}
```

How can I implement `isSubType` to get the correct result for types that are unknown at compile-time?

Note: I don't need this to be compatible with the JS runtime, just AOT and JIT compiled Dart.

Comment: FYI, 1. In you "with a static type" examples, you claim that `isSubType(<Iterable>[], <List>[])` is true, but it should be false.  2. In your "without a static type" examples, you're not doing the same checks as before; your arguments are reversed.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not aware of any way to do what you want with runtime types.  In general, there is not much that you can do with `Type` objects.  It might help to explain what problem you're ultimately trying to solve so that you don't fall into the trap of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/).

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to chcek the subtype relation of two types, you don't need arguments at all, only type arguments.

```dart
bool isSubtype<S, T>() => <S>[] is List<T>;
```

You also can't extract the runtime type of an object as a type argument.
I'm guessing that's what you are trying to do with the arguments and type inference, but type inference happens at compile-time and only uses the static types of the arguments.
The call `print(isSubType(type, a))` infers the type `List<dynamic>` for both type arguments from the expressions `type` and `a`, and does so at compile-time and independently of the actual run-time type that variable will contain.

There is no general way, outside of `dart:mirrors`, to check whether two objects have runtime types that are related to each other, *because* it's not possible to get the runtime type of an object into a type variable.

You also can't do anything similar with `Type` objects. A `Type` object is only really good for passing into `dart:mirrors`, and maybe compare for equality. It doesn't understand subtyping at all.